# How to disable default behavior of <input type="time"> when you press enter?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to disable default behavior of `<input type="time">` when you press enter. As demonstrated on the image below, when you press enter the browser shows time selector, however I don't want it show that instead on enter, I want to send a post request. Atm my onEnter() doesn't work. Thank you.

[image]

```
  const onEnter = (e) => {
       if (e.key === "Enter") {
           e.preventDefault();
           console.log('e:', e.target.value);
       }
   };
```

Comment: How are you hooking up that function to the element? That's a crucial bit of information for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is fine if you use it as a `keydown` handler (rather than `keypress`):

```js
const onEnter = (e) => {
     if (e.key === "Enter") {
         e.preventDefault();
         console.log('e:', e.target.value);
     }
};
document.getElementById("the-input").addEventListener("keydown", onEnter);
```

```html
<input type="time" id="the-input">
```

Tested and working on Chrome and Firefox. Legacy Edge opens the drop-down on focus, so its behavior doesn't depend on Enter being pressed. (The newer Chromium-based Edge presumably has Chrome's behavior.)

Comment: Thank you this worked. Is there a way to hide the clock icon?

Comment: @Jereme - I don't know. It sounds like you might want a `type="text`" instead, though...? If you don't want the usual browser-supplied time features... :-)